# How to SyncLock a Shared Integer

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, synclock

I am pretty new to multi-threading in general and I would like to know how can I lock a shared integer variable to not be accessed by other threads while it is read/updated by an other thread.

When I try do do `SyncLock myInteger`, I get that error : **Error 6 'SyncLock' operand cannot be of type 'Integer' because 'Integer' is not a reference type.**

Here a simplified example of what I mean

```
Private Shared myInteger As Integer

Private Sub MySub()
  SyncLock myInteger ' This does not work
    ' read/write a new value to myInteger
  End SyncLock
End Sub
```

MySub is called by multiple instances of the class, and running in multiple threads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you don't fully understand what `SyncLock` does. Even if you *could* do it (if `Integer` were a reference type, for example) you wouldn't *want* to do it - because when you replaced the value of `myInteger`, the lock would be useless.

You should *either* lock on something else (personally I generally declare a separate, read-only variable purely for the sake of locking, usually of type `Object`) or if you *only* want to operate on `myInteger` at any time (rather than some compound operation which needs to read or update several variables at the same time), use the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class.

Comment: Your suspicions are right, I don't fully understand what SyncLock does ;-) But with your explanation that it could be any trivial Object, just to keep the lock, I think I get a better idea. Thank you SO Grand Master ;-)